# Displaying multiple loops based off of category

Tags: categories, loop, feed

How do I get this loop to detect a specific category, and change the html if it's a different category.

In other words, if a the category is detected, I want to style the blogs with the specific category differently than what's currently spit out.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query(array(
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'order' => 'DESC'
)); ?>

<?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
<?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' );?>
<div class="row episodes-feed-wrap">
    <div class="col-4 episodes-feed-thumb">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large' ); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 featured-article">
        <div class="container" style="padding:0;">
            <h4 class="episodes-feed-cat">
            <?php $categories = get_the_category();
            if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
            }?>
            </h4>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <h2 class="episodes-title">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h2>
            </a>
            <div class="episodes-excerpt">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <?php echo excerpt(25); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="episodes-feed-info-wrap">
                <div class="episodes-feed-author">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                    <?php the_author(); ?>  &#8226; <?php echo meks_time_ago(); /* post date in time ago format */ ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end container --> 
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant in your question, you never actually state what the structure you wanted is. But judging from what I see in the code, are you trying to display posts in columns?

Comment: @TomJNowell I just want the existing loop above to recognize if a category is called "investments" and if it is, then it has it's own html structure.

Comment: So you're asking how to test if a post has a particular category or not? If that's the case, then the other stuff is a red herring that'll confuse people trying to read your question. Edit your question using the edit link to make it clear what you're asking. Note that any answer you get will require basic PHP skills to understand

Comment: @TomJNowell Ok I edited it. Thanks for you time.

Comment: What HTML are you trying to change? It would make it easier if you also added the markup for "Category X" posts.

Comment: @RLM I didn't notice a difference, if things are as I thought, then there's no need for the code block, and no need to mention HTML or code structure at all. It could be simplified down to this: `Given a post, how do I check if it is in a particular category X?`

Comment: @disinfor the html change is arbitrary, the point is I just want to be able to style certain blogs differently ( new html, css etc ) if they have a certain category.

Comment: @TomJNowell Changed it again. Couldn't be more clear.

Comment: It's not arbitrary. Are you trying to style the POST differently within that loop, or are you trying to style a category archive page differently? Your question is not clear in that regard.

Comment: @disinfor this is a loop that spits out blogs, i want to style blogs with a specific category differently then what's there now.

Comment: I know what the loop is doing. So what you want, is in this SAME loop, you want the HTML to change if the post has a specific category? So, the HTML will change in between the `episodes-feed-wrap` div. Is that correct?

Comment: @disinfor yes, that is correct. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_get_post_terms()` and `in_array()` to check if "investments" is in the term array or not:

```
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query(array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
)); ?>

<?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' );?>

    <?php
        // Gather all the post terms for the post.
        $post_term_objects = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
        // Empty array to hold our terms
        $post_terms = [];
        // loop through the objects and put the slug (this could be name as well, but slug is easier to manage)
        foreach ( $post_term_objects as $post_term_object ) {
            // put the terms into the array.
            $post_terms[] = $post_term_object->slug;
        }
    ?>

    <div class="row episodes-feed-wrap">
        <!-- CHECK IF investments is NOT in the array -->
        <?php if ( ! in_array( 'investments', $post_terms, false ) ) : ?>
            <div class="col-4 episodes-feed-thumb">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large' ); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 featured-article">
                <div class="container" style="padding:0;">
                    <h4 class="episodes-feed-cat">
                        <?php $categories = get_the_category();
                        if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
                        }?>
                    </h4>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                        <h2 class="episodes-title">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="episodes-excerpt">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                            <?php echo excerpt(25); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="episodes-feed-info-wrap">
                        <div class="episodes-feed-author">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                                <?php the_author(); ?>  &#8226; <?php echo meks_time_ago(); /* post date in time ago format */ ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- end container -->
            </div>
        <?php else : ?>
            <!-- PUT YOUR MARK UP FOR INVESTMENTS HERE -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I commented everything so you should be able to follow what is happening.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.